# Calling parametrized stored procedure using NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I want to call a stored procedure that return `ClassID` and `Student id`

My XML mapping is

```
<sql-query name="GetClassRevenuebyStudent_Sea">
    <return-scalar column="totalRevenew" type="System.String" />
    exec GetClassRevenue_Sea ClassID, StudentID
</sql-query>
```

And my stored procedure calling code is

```
public static double Student_ShowRevenue(string classid, string studentid)
{
    ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetSession();
    ITransaction trans = session.BeginTransaction();
    IQuery query = (IQuery)session.GetNamedQuery("GetClassRevenuebyStudent_Sea");
    query.SetParameter("ClassID", classid);
    query.SetParameter("StudentID", studentid);

    return Convert.ToDouble(query.List()[0]); 
}
```

But when I run the application it gives the exception on the line

```
return Convert.ToDouble(query.List()[0])
```

that all parameters are not set.

Comment: Have you tried defining your SP like exec GetClassRevenue_Sea :ClassID, :StudentID (with colons before your parameters names) ?

Comment: What kind of exception? (can you give the whole exception?)

Comment: `QueryException: All parameters are not set.` type exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place a colon in front of your `ClassId` and `StudentId` properties in your mapping to indicate that they are placeholders for the parameters you are going to set:

```
<sql-query name="GetClassRevenuebyStudent_Sea">
    <return-scalar column="totalRevenew" type="System.String" />
    exec GetClassRevenue_Sea :ClassID, :StudentID <!-- notice the colon (:) -->
</sql-query>
```

then you can call the named query from your code,

```
IQuery query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetClassRevenuebyStudent_Sea")
   .SetParameter("ClassID", classid)
   .SetParameter("StudentID", studentid);
```